# Control Embedded Grooveshark Widgets using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, flash, widget, audio-player, grooveshark

How would I play/pause an embedded Grooveshark widget using Javascript?

Would like to play separate single-song widgets in sequence, ala separate tracks on a [soundcloud user's page](http://soundcloud.com/tick_tock/favorites).

I didn't see anything officially supported, and couldn't find anything via googling.

Comment: I have the same problem :) I embeded widget and it startes automaticly but I want to trigger to pause when some action happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a quick glance at the decompiled actionscript and turned up the following ExternalInterface callbacks:

```
getVersion()
getCurrentSong()
setSongCompleteCallback(string)
setErrorCallback(string)
setStatusCallback(string)
setSongChangeCallback(string)
playSong()
pauseSong()
resumeSong()
stopSong()
replaceSongs(array)
```

In theory, you should be able to do something like the following:

```
widget.stopSong();
```